# Settings for the PhpStorm IDE

Tags: settings, phpstorm

Does anybody know how can I turn off or change the color to the cursor for the phpstorm IDE?. Please see the image attach.

[image: remove/change the blue color from the cursor]

Thank you so much.

Comment: Which color precisely? The blue background that highlights opening and closing braces (`<` and `>`)? If so -- do you want to change the color .. or remove such highlighting?

Comment: I would like to remove the blue background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General`
2. `Highlights on Caret Movement` section
3. Disable `Highlight matched brace` option

**P.S.**
You can use search box on the top left to quickly find option in Settings/Preferences screen.

---

If you want to change that color to another one:

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts| General`
2. `Code | Matched brace` (that's for v10; in v9 all styles are in single list and not grouped like in v10).

Comment: Absolutely awesome. Thanks for your time and effort. I wish to vote this but unfortunately I don't have enough credits. Again, thanks a lot. If I do not ask too much......is there any option to have the matched braces like in Notepad++? Is that vertical dotted red line. Thank you LazyOne.